# why triggers are used in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

We know that triggers  are implicitly executed when INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE operations take place on table.
my question is while using triggers NEW and OLD keyword give us new data and old data then why we use BEFORE or AFTER since we can able to retrieve old and new data using OLD and NEW. 
Why triggers are used and for what purpose BEFORE and AFTER are used

Answer (score 0):

when one needs to perform n numbers of operations before executing the insert/update/delete query, we used BEFORE. same with AFTER. NEW and OLD just signifies what the query makes a change to this data.

you can find the uses of triggers in wiki pages. mosting it is used to validate data before the query operation.